# Inserting multiple values in django database - raw sqlite statements

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I use the raw sql in django..

```
p.execute('''INSERT INTO webapp_information VALUES(login=%s, idd=%s, avatar_url=%s, gravatar_id=%s, url=%s, html_url=%s, followers_url=%s, following_url=%s, gists_url=%s, starred_url=%s, subscriptions_url=%s, organizations_url=%s, repos_url=%s, events_url=%s, received_events_url=%s,typ=%s,site_admin=%s, name=%s, company=%s, blog=%s, location=%s,email=%s, hireable=%s, bio=%s, public_repos=%s, public_gists=%s, followers=%s, following=%s, created_at=%s, updated_at=%s, dat=%s''',i)
```

i is the list of values

follow the custom sql given in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
 77         start = time()
 78         try:
---> 79             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
 80         finally:
 81             stop = time()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
 62                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
 63             else:
--> 64                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 65 
 66     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.pyc in __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
 92                 if dj_exc_type not in (DataError, IntegrityError):
 93                     self.wrapper.errors_occurred = True
---> 94                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
 95 
 96     def __call__(self, func):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
 62                 return self.cursor.execute(sql)
 63             else:
---> 64                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 65 
 66     def executemany(self, sql, param_list):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.pyc in execute(self, query, params)
335             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
336         query = self.convert_query(query)    
--> 337         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
338 
339     def executemany(self, query, param_list):

OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

i never used the '?'  where the django asked to use '%s' 
what to do.. thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this as raw SQL? It's a simple insert, which maps straight onto a model create call

Comment: How to do that.. <br> And It is also easier to use the raw sql statements.. so I used it but got error.. and how to resolve it.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your i variable must be a list
i=[...]
p variable is a cursor object
p.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO
webapp_information(login, idd, avatar_url, gravatar_id, url, html_url, followers_url, following_url, gists_url, starred_url, subscriptions_url, organizations_url, repos_url, events_url, received_events_url,typ,site_admin, name, company, blog, location, email, hireable, bio, public_repos, public_gists, followers, following, created_at, updated_at, dat) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',i)